# How to find that a picture is taken with the smartphone camera or is taken from internet, programmatically?

Tags: image, image-processing, file-upload, image-recognition

I am building an e-commerce platform and I want that shopkeepers upload original pictures of the items only. So, is there any way to find that the picture shopkeeper is uploading is taken by camera or not.

Comment: What if the picture downloaded from the Web was taken by a camera ? (which is the case for about 100% of them)

Comment: It must be but it may not be by the same phone camera

Comment: There is zero chance that you can tell the mismatch.